# Delooping higher groupoid

Tags: higher-category-theory

I am trying to learn the following ideas of groups and groupoids. Am a bit confused regarding the following ideas.

I have learned BA is a 2-group with a single object and the space of morphisms to be A. Why abelian groups are required? Also, is BA a groupoid?
Also, for G being a discrete group, BG is a groupoid with a single object and the space of morphisms to be G. Why isn't BG a 2-group here?
For A being an abelian group, B$^2$A is also a 3-group besides being a 2-groupoid, right?
What is the generic way to see which ones are higher groupoids and which ones are higher groups? I would like to know systematically. As far as I know, n-groups are the group objects in the (n,1) category (n-1)Grpd (made out of (n-1) groupoids). Or, the n-group is the pointed, connected n-groupoid.
Thanks.
I have just completed my undergrad in physics, apologies if these sound trivial.

Comment: Recall that a set $G$ being a group is an extra structure. Similarly, an $\infty$-groupoid being an $E_1$-group is an extra structure. If $A$ is an abelian group, the claim is that the groupoid $BA$ carries an extra $E_1$-group structure (in fact, it carries an $E_\infty$-group structure).

Answer (score 4):

> I have learned BA is a 2-group with a single object and the space of morphisms to be A. Why abelian groups are required?

I think there is some confusion with the statement $BA$ is a 2-group. This probably stems from the initial point-of-view of what groups are.

Littered throughout the web you will come across claims that "a group is the same thing as a category with a single object and only isomorphisms", i.e. a groupoid with a single object (equivalent to being pointed and connected). This is very misleading since nobody really *defines* groups this way, but it is really trying to emphasise the fact that a group $G$ and its delooping $BG$ as a category contain the same "information".

Using this misleading definition that $G$ is really defined as $BG$, then the actual $BG$ in this context would have to be a 2-groupoid since it would be the delooping of a 1-groupoid.

It is perhaps enticing to define a group as a pointed conencted 1-groupoid, but in my experience it doesn't gain you anything in practice.

> Why abelian groups are required?

Abelian groups are not required for a delooping $BG$, but for higher deloopings this is the "only interesting case" as $\Omega B^2G \cong B G^{ab}$. The $\Omega$ operation is known as a loop space in algebraic topology but here you can think of it directly as $Hom(id,id)$. This is a way of "shifting down" morphisms from a higher level. (The opposite of what B does).

The reason for this is studied in algebraic topology and stems from the Eckmann-Hilton argument. If you have 2-morphisms then there is always a way to shift them around to commute, hence all non-abelian group data automatically gets abelianized when shifted to level 2 and above.

> Also, is BA a groupoid?

As per the discussion above, yes, in the sense that it is a 1-category with only isomoprhisms. But in this case it is pointed and connected.

> Also, for G being a discrete group, BG is a groupoid with a single object and the space of morphisms to be G. Why isn't BG a 2-group here?

If you define a group as a single object groupoid then yes, it is a 2-group. If you define it as a usual group and BG as a 1-groupoid then no, its just a 1-groupoid.

Comment: Thank you. So, if we take G to be a single object groupoid, B$^n$G can be seen as either an n-groupoid or (n+1)-group. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, but I would always imagine that the first is intended unless explicitly intended otherwise.